# Выдаётся ошибка при открытии csv-файла в Python:UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 3812: character maps to undefin

Tags: python, pandas

При  открытии файла при помощи Pandas в Python мне выдаётся эта ошибка. Изначально файл был в .numbers -программе, но так как мне удобнее работать с csv, я его форматировала. Файл выглядит вот так:

> id pos category    stereotype  lemma   level
> id  pos category    stereotype  lemma   level
> RU1466  n   re  no  Декриминализация    inclusive
> RU2548  n   re  no  nostra  inclusive
> RU469   n   cds no  франт   inclusive
> RU1412  n   om  no  сударыня    inclusive

Вот пример кода:

```
df.to_csv('hate_speech.csv', index = False, sep = "\t")
df_hate_speech_lexicon = pd.read_csv("/hate_speech_lexicon_csv.csv", engine="python", encoding="cp1251")
```

С чем связана эта ошибка и как можно ее можно убрать, чтобы я могла дальше работать с файлом?

Comment: Попробуйте заменить на `..., encoding="utf-8"`

Comment: Выдаётся новая ошибка:ParserError      Traceback (most recent call last)

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте

```
df_hate_speech_lexicon = pd.read_csv("/hate_speech_lexicon_csv.csv", sep='\t')
```

так как в `read_csv` по умолчанию стоит `sep = ','`

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).